# Firebase Multi Factor Authentication for a web app returns "auth/code-expired" error

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, multi-factor-authentication

I'm trying to implement multi-factor authentication to my web application built with Angular, which throws the following error: **"auth/code-expired", "The SMS code has expired. Please resend the verification code to try again."** even though I enter the code in a minute.

I've manually registered my phone number(iPhone) to the ID platform, and able to receive a verification code to my phone.
Also, if I enter my phone number and verification code into the ID platform for development purpose, I can sign in without any problem.

I've read this question but seems not applicable in my case as the auth state does not change when I receive verification codes.
[The sms code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57054891/the-sms-code-has-expired-please-re-send-the-verification-code-to-try-again)

Can anyone tell me what's wrong? Below is the code I have.

```
    <section>
      <h4>Sign in with MFA</h4>
      <div class="flex">
        <input placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="email">
        <input placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="pass">
        <button (click)="onAuth()">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section>
      <div style="position:relative;z-index:10;width:100%;margin-top:2em;margin-left:2em;margin-right:auto;">
        <div id="recaptcha-container"></div>
      </div>
   </section>

   <section>
     {{ user$ | async | json }}
   </section>
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
firebase.default.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  email: string = 'myEmail@gmail.com';
  pass = 'myPassword';


  windowRef;
  resolver;
  user$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(
    private fireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.user$ = this.fireAuth.user;
    this.windowRef = window;
    this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.default.auth
      .RecaptchaVerifier(
        'recaptcha-container',
        {
          'size': 'invisible',
          'callback': (response) => {
            console.log('recapcha solved', response);
          }
        });
  }


  onAuth() {
    this.fireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.pass)
      .then(result => {
        alert('Sign in Success');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Sign-in catch block', err);
        if (err.code === 'auth/multi-factor-auth-required') {
          alert('MFA required');
          this.resolver = err.resolver;
          const selectedIndex = 0;
          // Ask user which second factor to use.
          if (this.resolver.hints[selectedIndex].factorId === firebase.default.auth.PhoneMultiFactorGenerator.FACTOR_ID) {
            const phoneNumber = prompt('Enter your phone number with a country code (e.g. +18881231234).');
            const phoneInfoOptions = {
              multiFactorHint: this.resolver.hints[selectedIndex],
              session: this.resolver.session,
              phoneNumber
            };
            const phoneAuthProvider = new firebase.default.auth.PhoneAuthProvider();
            // Send SMS verification code
   
            return phoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(phoneInfoOptions.phoneNumber, this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier)
              .then((verificationId) => {
                // Ask user for the SMS verification code.
                const verificationCode = prompt('Enter the 6 digits verification code you received.');

                const cred = firebase.default.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, verificationCode);
                const multiFactorAssertion =
                  firebase.default.auth.PhoneMultiFactorGenerator.assertion(cred);

                const result = this.resolver.resolveSignIn(multiFactorAssertion);
                console.log('result', result); // **throws auth/code-expired**

                // Complete sign-in.
                return result;
              })
              .then((userCredential) => {
                // User successfully signed in with the second factor phone number.
                console.log('MFA success', userCredential);

              });
          } else {
            // Unsupported second factor.
            console.log('Unsupported second factor.');

          }
        } else {
          alert('Sign in Failed');
        }
      });

  }

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem, but will leave it as a record.
The following code was incorrect:

```
// Incorrect

          if (this.resolver.hints[selectedIndex].factorId === firebase.default.auth.PhoneMultiFactorGenerator.FACTOR_ID) {
            const phoneNumber = prompt('Enter your phone number with a country code (e.g. +18881231234).');
            const phoneInfoOptions = {
              multiFactorHint: this.resolver.hints[selectedIndex],
              session: this.resolver.session,
              phoneNumber
            };
            const phoneAuthProvider = new firebase.default.auth.PhoneAuthProvider();
            // Send SMS verification code
   
            return phoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(phoneInfoOptions.phoneNumber, this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier)
              .then((verificationId) => {...
```

Once I take **phoneNumber** away from the phoneInfoOptions and provide phoneInfoOptions to verifyPhoneNumber(), MFA does successfylly go through.

```
// Correct

          if (this.resolver.hints[selectedIndex].factorId === firebase.default.auth.PhoneMultiFactorGenerator.FACTOR_ID) {
            prompt('Enter your phone number with a country code (e.g. +18881231234).');
            const phoneInfoOptions = {
              multiFactorHint: this.resolver.hints[selectedIndex],
              session: this.resolver.session,
            };
            const phoneAuthProvider = new firebase.default.auth.PhoneAuthProvider();
            // Send SMS verification code
   
            return phoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(phoneInfoOptions, this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier)
              .then((verificationId) => {...
```