# Error: auth / session-expired The sms code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication

I am implementing Firebase authentication in my app. I had started facing this issue since firebase package are upgrade from "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^12.4.0" to "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^12.8.0".

I have checked older question related this issue but they are too old and the answer are not solving the issue.

Strange is I am able to login sometimes and sometime not. The play store version is not at all working. It always shows this error.

Below are the library I am using:
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.8.0",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^12.8.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^12.8.0",

All 3(debug,release,google) SHA256 key are added in firebase app. Am in dead loop now.

```
async function signInWithPhoneNumber() {
console.log('Inside the Phone Number +91', registration_id);
try {
  const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(
    '+91' + registration_id,
  );
  setConfirm(confirmation);
} catch (_error) {
  console.log(_error);
}
```

}

```
async function confirmCode(code) {
try {
  result = await confirm.confirm(code);
  uid = result.user.uid;
  console.log('result from confirmcode function:', uid);
} catch (_error) {
  console.log('Invalid code.', _error);
}
```

}

Thanking in Advance.

Comment: Check the following question. I think it is the same problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57054891/the-sms-code-has-expired-please-re-send-the-verification-code-to-try-again